# How many players can play in a regular LAN multiplayer world in Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm planning on doing a minecraft event with my friends. Last I heard, up to ten players could play in one world. Last time I saw, it was five. Is it five or ten?

Comment: This depends on many factors, such as server capability, world size, mods installed and active, and probably a host of others that I missed.  There's no real way to answer this.

Comment: 5 is the default max number of players if you connect directly. With a server you can easily have more than that.

Comment: I'm talking about a regular LAN world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is currently 5, but the /setmaxplayers command can increase it up to 30.

Comment: In the pocket edition?

Comment: @Calvinface Yes